# Excel VBA / Macro - TextToColumns for multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there way to find cell that contains "Date" and run the TextToColumns macro?
instead of referencing column "H" or "J" and/or so on...

Ultimately I am trying to change about 5 columns that contains "~ Date" to TextToColumn.
And it's not always on the "H" column.

Thank you so much for your expertise

```
Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("H1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 5), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Is the cell that contains "Date" the header, or are you just looking for columns where any cell contains "Date"?

Comment: First thanks for your interest!
Just "Date" in header, then I can just fill it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "date" values are to be found in the column headers for row 1, the following code should do the trick.

It works as follows:

- find the rightmost column header in row 1
- loop through the first to last header
- search for the string "date" within each header cell

  -- if not found, go to the next header cell

  -- if found, then convert the text values of the column of date for that header into columns and go to the next header cell

Note that I removed the `Selects` from the code, which are not necessary to do the conversions.

Your description was not clear on whether there were enough blank columns to the right of a "date"-headed column to hold the split data without overwriting other existing data. *This procedure assumes that there is enough room.* As a result, if there is data in the cells to the right, Excel will show a dialog box asking if you want to overwrite the adjacent cell.  If there is not, and additional columns need to inserted, please modify your question to make that clear.

```
  Sub txttocol()

      Dim ws As Sheet1
      Dim rng As Range
      Dim lastCol As Long
      Dim i As Long

      Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
      With ws
          lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          For i = 1 To lastCol
              If InStr(UCase(.Cells(1, i).Value), UCase("date")) <> 0 Then
                  Set rng = .Range(Columns(i), Columns(i))
                  rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                      Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                      :=Array(1, 5), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
              End If
          Next i
      End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: It's very concise, but how does it answer the question? :)

Comment: Fair comment - Rereading the question, it's an incomplete response -- addressing only the part of the question that asks how to refer to columns by number. I will withdraw it for now.

Comment: Good answer with good description of the potential risk of overwriting data. +1